# S3DistCp Grouping by Folder

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

I'm trying to use `S3DistCp` to get around the small files problem in Hadoop. It's working, but the output is a bit annoying to work with. The file path's I'm dealing with are like :

```
s3://test-bucket/test/0000eb6e-4460-4b99-b93a-469d20543bf3/201402.csv
```

and there can be multiple files within that folder. I want to group by the folder name, so I use the following group by argument in s3distcp:

```
--groupBy '.*(........-.........-....-............).*'
```

and it does group the files, but it results it still results in multiple output folders, with one file in each folder. Is there any way to output the grouped files into one folder, instead of multiple?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Binal Patel: If you post the log generated by your s3distCp I will be able to better help you.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2015-11-20, this is the behavior of S3DistCp. It will create multiple directories based on the source directories. It will not combine across directories.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try out this:
`--groupBy ".*/(........-.........-....-............)/.*"`

In your example you should use something like:  `--src "s3://test-bucket/test/"`

This way you will have multiple folders with all files inside those folders merged together.

Comment: I am trying figure out something like that but couldnt achieve it.